# Prove the uniqueness of functional equation

Tags: functions

How do one prove the uniqueness of a functional equation. (elementary) not functional analysis class...

For example, if we have $f(x+y)=x+f(y)$ and $f(0)=1$.  Letting y=0, we obtain $f(x)=x+1.$
But how do you prove that the function I derived is just the function satisfies the above relationship.

Comment: You've got a necessary condition on your function (ie f(x) = x+1 ) , now you have to check that this very function satisfies all the conditions you've started with. If yes, it is the only one, if not there is no solutions. That's a type of reasoning called (I translate from french) analysis and synthesis.

Comment: Why would you need to check back to see if the derived function does satisfy? I mean, what does it mean by  IF a function $f$ satisfies your functional equation, THEN one must have $f(x)=x+1 $ If you proved it, why do you still have to show $f(x)=x+1 $ satisfy the given condition since you already the showed the only function satisfy the given condition is $f(x)=x+1 $ .

Comment: No, because there is no equivalency in your reasoning. You proved that if f(x+y) = x + f(y) then by saying y=0 you have f(x) = x + f(0), but this not equivalent to your functional equation at all. It is a consequence, not a sufficient and necessary condition

Comment: So you have to check back, to see if deductions will completely fit your conditions you've started with.

Comment: Can you please give me a example where my reasoning fails please?

Comment: An example of a function where there are no solutions is f(x+y) = xf(y) and f(0)=1. Then, you could set y=0 to obtain that f(x) = x. This is a necessary condition, but not sufficient (e.g. compute f(0) - you get 0 which contradicts the desired condition)

Comment: But if there is a contradiction, why is f(x)=x still a necessary condition?

Comment: Ok try this: suppose you want to solve :
 f(x+1) =$f(x)^2$ , f is real value. Then this implies : f(x) $\geq$ 0, but not all positive functions verify your functionnal equation from the start

Comment: f(x) $\geq$ 0 on [1, +inf[ at least

Comment: If you prefer: an implication reduces the strength of the hypothesis, it gives lesser conditions since there is no equivalency. So whenever you make a deduction, you allow more functions to be found in exchange for more information and more precision. But if you wanted these functions to be the complete and only possible solutions, you would have to get back step by step, so in fact build an equivalency, not simple implications

Comment: I feel like it is just like solving for a variable. like solving for x. For example, $x^2+3x+1=0$ implies $x=r_1,x=r_2,$ but we are never taught to verify these since every step is reversible. Is there a step that is not reversible done in solving for functional equations?

Comment: You got it, the step where you say y=0 reduces the hypothesis, since you don't take into account all real numbers for y, only 0. In that case you can make an equivalency so it's not a very good example, but like my example or certain other problems like these ones, you don't have it

Answer (score 1):

You just computed it: this is the best possible case, when you can compute the solution explicitly. You have shown that IF a function $f$ satisfies your functional equation, THEN one must have $f(x)=x+1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. In particular, the solution to that equation is unique.